# Multiple joins in annotation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-aggregation

I have a `Post` model which has ManyToMany relation with `User` to reflect Likes feature. Moreover `Post` has ForeignKey relation to itself since each post can be a comment to existing `Post` (only one depth level is forced - there are no discussion trees).

Now I'm trying to use aggregates to get most active discussions. I want to calculate score for each `Post` which is sum of its likes, comments, and likes of its comments.

Following SQL works perfectly:

```
SELECT "posting_post"."id",
       "posting_post"."title",
       "posting_post"."content",
       "posting_post"."pub_date",
       "posting_post"."parent_id",
       "posting_post"."user_id",
       COUNT(DISTINCT T4."id") AS "cc",
       COUNT(DISTINCT "posting_post_likes"."id") AS "lc",
       COUNT(DISTINCT T7."id") AS "clc"
FROM "posting_post"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "posting_post" T4 ON ("posting_post"."id" = T4."parent_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "posting_post_likes" ON ("posting_post"."id" = "posting_post_likes"."post_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "posting_post_likes" T7 ON (T4."id" = T7."post_id")
WHERE "posting_post"."parent_id" IS NULL
GROUP BY "posting_post"."id",
         "posting_post"."title",
         "posting_post"."content",
         "posting_post"."pub_date",
         "posting_post"."parent_id",
         "posting_post"."user_id"
ORDER BY cc+lc+clc DESC LIMIT 10
```

When I try to use aggreagtions:

```
Post.objects.filter(parent=None).annotate(clc=models.Count('comments__likes', discinct=True), cc=models.Count('comments', distinct=True), lc=models.Count('likes', distinct=True))[:10]
```

Following SQL is generated:

```
SELECT "posting_post"."id",
       "posting_post"."title",
       "posting_post"."content",
       "posting_post"."pub_date",
       "posting_post"."parent_id",
       "posting_post"."user_id",
       COUNT(DISTINCT T4."id") AS "cc",
       COUNT(DISTINCT "posting_post_likes"."user_id") AS "lc",
       COUNT(T7."user_id") AS "clc"
FROM "posting_post"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "posting_post" T4 ON ("posting_post"."id" = T4."parent_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "posting_post_likes" ON ("posting_post"."id" = "posting_post_likes"."post_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "posting_post_likes" T7 ON (T4."id" = T7."post_id")
WHERE "posting_post"."parent_id" IS NULL
GROUP BY "posting_post"."id",
         "posting_post"."title",
         "posting_post"."content",
         "posting_post"."pub_date",
         "posting_post"."parent_id",
         "posting_post"."user_id"
ORDER BY "posting_post"."pub_date" DESC LIMIT 10
```

Which is not working as I expect. Please note main difference:
`COUNT(DISTINCT T7."id") AS "clc"`
vs.
`COUNT(T7."user_id") AS "clc"`

Is there some way to force django to count `id` instead of `user_id` or some more clever way of using aggregates to achieve results like first SQL returns?

Comment: why do you have `distinct=True`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Without discint=True numbers are totally wrong. When I have single annotation it's not necessary but there are three of them.